# Find command with If not working as it should

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, find

Hi  here is my code from module called extract 
The logfile is the file I produce from another function within the same script
calls extract function  ..

```
 : extract 
  find /c "extract return code: 0" c:\hp\logs\!logfile!
 SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
 echo errorleve with percent %errorlevel%
 echo errorleve with dxcalim  !errorlevel!
 if !errorlevel! NEQ 0 (    
     echo do something 
  ) else (
 echo do nothing 
 )
```

)

Ok lets say my logfile has the following entry

```
  extract return code: 0
```

The result is as follow:

```
 ---------- C:\HP\LOGS\logfilename: 1
 errorleve with percent 0
 errorleve with dxcalim  0
 do something
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

If  my logfile has the following entry

```
  extract return code: 1
```

The result is as follow:

```
 ---------- C:\HP\LOGS\logfilename.txt: 0
 errorleve with percent 0
 errorleve with dxcalim  0
 do something
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see the line result are different but the errorlevel remains the same
     ---------- C:\HP\LOGS\logfilename: 1
     ----------  C:\HP\LOGS\logfilename.txt: 0

So my if and else statement are not picking up the errorlevel correctly? 
This code works fine outside of this script ; that is why I'm very puzzled.
If I run the same code against a text file it works fine but when I make it into a function and call it within another script it falls apart?

What am I doing wrong? Is the $errorlevel% not the correct thing to check?
I tried both !errorlevel!  and %errorlevel%  .. I get same result

Answer (score 0):

`SETLOCAL` is clearing `errorlevel`.

Try moving the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` before the `find`.

---

Addendum: actual test batch and results

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
>q18906531.txt ECHO extract return code: 0
CALL :test
>q18906531.txt ECHO extract return code: 1
CALL :test
GOTO :eof

:test
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
find /c "extract return code: 0" q18906531.txt
echo errorleve with percent %errorlevel%
echo errorleve with dxcalim  !errorlevel!
if !errorlevel! NEQ 0 (    
    echo do something 
 ) else (
echo do nothing 
) 
endlocal
GOTO :EOF
```

Result:

```
---------- Q18906531.TXT: 1
errorleve with percent 0
errorleve with dxcalim  0
do nothing 

---------- Q18906531.TXT: 0
errorleve with percent 1
errorleve with dxcalim  1
do something
```

Works for me!

Comment: It looks like find does change the errorlevel when counting, based on found/not_found too.

Answer (score 0):

This will also give you a changing errorlevel (0 when found and 1 when not)

```
find "extract return code: 0" < "c:\hp\logs\!logfile!" >nul
```

Be aware that other commands will change the errorlevel so test it (or save it) before using other commands.